# How to convert numeric to time (hh:mm) in R?

Tags: r, time, type-conversion

I have a series of number from 1 to 288, I want to convert 1 to 11:00, 2 to 11:05, 3 to 11:10, etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that by `time`, you mean a POSIXct object:

```
start <- as.POSIXct(x = "11:00", format = "%H:%M")
seq(from = start, by = "5 mins", length.out = 288)
```

Comment: Thanks, I added `format(time,"%H:%M")` and got what I want.